# How to run a http.request inside a imported module. Its not running when I am trying to access

Tags: javascript, node.js

My main.js file:

```
var spaceJson = require('./space.js');
var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "10.10.111.226",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/API/Org",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG...",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"   
  }
};
var JSONdata = spaceJson.space.getSpaceData(options);
```

my space.js file(this actually is making a request to a web api and returns json)

```
var module = module.exports = {};
var http = require("http");

module.space = {

sayHelloInSpanish: function() {
    return "Hola";
  },

getSpaceData : function(options) {
var body = '';
 http.request(options, function (req,res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {  
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    body = Buffer.concat(chunks);   
    console.log(body.toString());

   });
    req.end();
  });
//return http.get();
}

};

var require = function(path){
return module.exports;
};
```

when I call
 `sayHelloInSpanish` 
method, it returns *"holla"* when I run main.js. But when I call the 
`getSpaceData`
 I dont see anything on command line and it hangs. Maybe I am not handling callback. With this I basically want to consume JSON data in my main.js

Answer (score 0):

You don't see anything because The HTTP response is async.
You should return a callback or use a promise:

```
getSpaceData : function(options, clbk) {
var body = '';
 http.request(options, function (req,res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {  
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    body = Buffer.concat(chunks);   
    console.log(body.toString());
    clbk(body.toString());
   });
    req.end();
  });
}

spaceJson.space.getSpaceData(options, function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

I recommend you to watch this video: https://vimeo.com/96425312

**-- UPDATE --**

Delete the require code:

```
var require = function(path){
return module.exports;
};
```

add to main:

```
// main.js
var spaceJson = require("./space.js");
```

Comment: Checked the video it was good. But even after adding the callback I still don't see any data. The call is not going in the http.request function at all. Is it something inherently due to http.request ?

Comment: check out [https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback], I think your options have a problem. why is the port assignment to null?

Comment: if its null it takes 80 by default. The code which is in space.js was a part of main.js and it was getting the data. I just refactored it to a seperate js file to make main.js handle other stuff.

Comment: Add `on.('error'`, see what the request problem. I think the listener is down or some other problem with the options